# Data leakage: Train test split before or after data preprocessing?

Tags: machine-learning, data-preprocessing, train-test-split, data-leakage

A while ago I came across the word "data leakage" for the first time, and after some research, I found that it is a common mistake among data science/machine learning practitioners. But the problem is that most of the data science projects I worked on Kaggle do the train test split after the data preprocessing step, knowing that this might cause the data leakage problem.
My question is: as a data scientist should I first do the train test split and then preprocess each set individually, or do the train test split after data preprocessing the whole dataset? Thank you

Comment: Split then process.

Comment: @user2974951 thank you, so most of the flowchart on machine learning development are wrong? they usually put train test split after data preprocessing

Comment: Maybe, depends. If the process step involves, for ex., transforming km to miles then no, there won't be any data leakage, or if a month variable is added, etc.. As long as the processing does not "taint" the test set it will be fine.

Comment: @user2974951 thank you, appreciate your help and your time

Comment: Like previously stated, it's a bit difficult to say in general, but data leakage can occur when preprocessing before splitting if anything that is done to the whole data set imparts knowledge of the whole data set into each observation, e.g. in a univariate regression problem, normalizing the regressor and target variable observations by subtracting their respective sample means and dividing by their respective sample standard deviations _before_ splitting can cause data leakage as the sample means and standard deviations of the variables for the whole data set become "known" to the subsets.

Comment: Further to [your comment](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/626729/data-leakage-train-test-split-before-or-after-data-preprocessing#comment1168931_626729): there are absolutely breathtakingly, astoundingly, incredibly bad websites out there, *especially* in data science and machine learning, but also in statistics, which provide advice that is simply WRONG. The better outcome is when people ask here. The worse outcome is when they simply apply the half-knowledge they found somewhere on the internet. The worst outcome is when they post about it and perpetuate the misinformation.

Comment: [More threads on this topic here.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=split+before+or+after+preprocessing)